# ¿Cual puede ser la causa del error "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", en éste caso?

Tags: python, pandas

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame.

```
resultados =  datos_basicos[["Fecha_Inv", "Fech_End_Anal","Cotiz_Ini_Anal", "Cotiz_End_Anal"]]
# Creamos dos columnas nuevas
resultados = resultados.reindex(columns = resultados.columns.tolist() + ["NDias", "CAGR"])
resultados.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 14 entries, TrueValue to renta4
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   Fecha_Inv       14 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Fech_End_Anal   14 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 2   Cotiz_Ini_Anal  14 non-null     float64       
 3   Cotiz_End_Anal  14 non-null     float64       
 4   NDias           0 non-null      float64       
 5   CAGR            0 non-null      float64
```

Necesito introducir en la columna "NDias", los días resultado de restar las fechas de las columnas siguientes

```
resultados["NYears"] = (resultados["Fech_End_Anal"] - resultados["Fecha_Inv"])
```

El resultado de esta sentencia, me devuelve  los dias, pero en formato timedelta64[ns]

```
           Fecha_Inv Fech_End_Anal  Cotiz_Ini_Anal  Cotiz_End_Anal  NDias  \
Nombre                                                                      
TrueValue 2017-10-11    2020-09-15          12.689          16.069    NaN   
TrueValue 2018-01-08    2020-09-15          12.689          16.069    NaN   

           CAGR    NYears  
Nombre                     
TrueValue   NaN 1070 days  
TrueValue   NaN  981 days
```

Mi objetivos final es tener el número de años transcurridos entre cada dos fechas, como número decimal. Para ello hago

```
resultados["NYears"] = (resultados["Fech_End_Anal"] - resultados["Fecha_Inv"]) 
resultados["NYears"]  = (pd.to_numeric(resultados["NYears"] .dt.days, downcast='float')) 
resultados["NYears"] = resultados["NYears"]/365
```

Esto me devuelve

```
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   Fecha_Inv       14 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Fech_End_Anal   14 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 2   Cotiz_Ini_Anal  14 non-null     float64       
 3   Cotiz_End_Anal  14 non-null     float64       
 4   NYears          14 non-null     float32       
 5   CAGR            0 non-null      float32
```

Si a continuación opero con estos campos, para calcular la columna "CAGR",

```
resultados["CAGR"] =  get_CAGR(resultados["Valor_Ini_Anal"],resultados["Valor_End_Anal"],resultados["NYears"])
```

me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-b7f046c64997> in <module>
      8 resultados["NYears"] = resultados["NYears"]/365
      9 
---> 10 resultados["CAGR"] =  get_CAGR(resultados["Valor_Ini_Anal"],resultados["Valor_End_Anal"],resultados["NYears"])
     11 resultados[:3]

<ipython-input-172-bfa37d17d58d> in get_CAGR(v1, v2, nYears)
      5     nYears : Duration of the investment.
      6     '''
----> 7     v_grow = float(v2)/v1
      8     cagr   = v_grow**(1./nYears) - 1
      9     return cagr

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    127         if len(self) == 1:
    128             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 129         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    130 
    131     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

¿Está relacionado con el hecho de que el tipo de datos que me devuelve para la columna "Nyears", es float32?.

Agradeceré sugerencias para resolver este problema.

Función CAGR

```
def get_CAGR(v1,v2,nYears):
    '''
    v1 : Initial value of the investment.
    v2 : Final value of the investment.
    nYears : Duration of the investment.
    '''
    v_grow = float(v2)/v1
    cagr   = v_grow**(1./nYears) - 1
    return cagr
```

He resuelto el problema eliminando la función,poniendo:

```
resultados["CAGR"] =  (resultados["Valor_End_Anal"] / resultados["Valor_Ini_Anal"])**(1./ resultados["NYears"])-1
```

Comment: ¿ podrías agregar la definición del método get_CAGR a la pregunta ?

Comment: He encontrado una solución y la he añadido en la pregunta. ¿Elimino esta pregunta?.

Comment: Puedes añadir la solución y autoresponderte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto el problema eliminando la función, de la siguiente manera.

```
resultados["CAGR"] =  (resultados["Valor_End_Anal"] / resultados["Valor_Ini_Anal"])**(1./ resultados["NYears"])-1
```